# CLLocationCoordinate2D to LocationList

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, cllocationcoordinate2d

Can I save the content of a CLLocationCoordinate2D array into a LocationList (Cloud Kit field type) ?

Here is what I've done, the TTitre is saved into the DB but not my CLLOcationCoordonate2D array

```
    let database = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase

    var TraceTitre = "Titre" as CKRecordValue
    var TabAsCK = traces as CKRecordValue


    let newTrace = CKRecord(recordType: "Trace")
    newTrace["TTitre"] = TraceTitre
    newTrace["TTrace"] = TabAsCK

    database.save(newTrace, completionHandler: { (record:CKRecord?, error:Error?) -> Void in
        if error != nil{
            print("Record OK \(record)")
        }
    })
```

Merci d'avance,
Florian

Comment: Yes. Can you provide code to show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solved the issue : 
You can't save a CLLocationCoordinate array but only a CLLocation array.
But if someone can explain me why ? Because CLLocationCoordinate2D can store only latitude and longitude values (which fit perfectly with a Location List field) contrary to CLLocation who can store Latitude, Longitude but also altitude...

Comment: Never played with CloudKit, but I guess that there could be an issue on Objective-C that would explain that: `CLLocation` is an object that is *NS(Secure)Coding* compliant, while `CLLocationCoordinate2D` is a struct which isn't *NSCoding* compliant. *NSCoding* is a protocol that ensure that the object can be transformed into `NSData`, and reverse. That's used for instance when you want to save an object into `NSUserDefaults`. I separated Objective-C and Swift, because for instance, we can't have a `NSArray` of structs (`CLLocationCoordinate2D`), but needs objects (with wrapper for instance).